# To try with someone,what does that mean?

Tags: word-usage

Micheal Scott is speaking with his boss,Jan, on the phone and making her upset so she is about to hang up.she says: i have really tried with you today.what does that mean?

Comment: You haven't told us who these people are, but presumably Jan has been trying hard to persuade Michael of something, or to change his mental outlook in some way.

Comment: It seems to me to mean "_**I've had enough of [dealing with] you** today_" or "_**I've dealt with you enough** today_".

Comment: So why did she use "try"?I looked up in dictionaries,but there was not any meaning of 'Try' in the sense of being tired

Comment: It means she has really tried to get along with him, but she's giving it up as a lost cause.

Comment: Please see https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4796/3395 and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/3395 to help you figure out how to format your post, and how to use punctuation properly.

Answer (score 1):

To try with someone means to make an effort to make something about your interaction or your relationship which is normally difficult a little easier/better.

Perhaps because of the lack of control of another person's reactions and the difficulty of controlling one's own, it's very common to talk about "trying to" do something in interpersonal relationships.  For example:

"I know I should try to be more patient with him."
"Try to see things from her point of view."
"Try not to antagonize Chris".

Often when someone used the phrase to try with someone, they have a specific effort in mind.  So when Jan says, "I really tried with you", she could mean "I really tried to be patient with you", just leaving the to be patient implied.  Some context about the people involved and/or the difficulties in the relationship are needed to know what is implied.